# Is there a way I can use the output of a custom action to set a wix property?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am working on a problem in WIX where the outcome of a custom action needs to dictate whether the next custom action will run. Is this possible? A script will be run on the installing machine that will query the running processes to find out if it is on the special machine. The outcome of this script needs to be used to decide if the next custom action should be run.

I have found [this gem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which shows that there is quite a bit of control when it comes to deciding to run a custom action, but there is still the issue of actually getting a relevant value set.

A last-resort solution I have thought of is to have the initial custom action use setx to set an environment variable, but this will leave behind the residual environment variable used to control the flow of the installer. A post-installer can be used to clean that up as well, but it just keeps getting uglier and uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would write a custom action to query for your process and call MsiSetProperty() to set a property ( let's say PROCFOUND = 1 ).  Then you'd use that in a component condition to control installing that component.  Finally your custom action would run if said component had an action state of installing. See:

[Conditional Statement Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx)